# Do Loop for every two rows in SAS

Tags: loops

My dataset looks something like this

eom_stock_id    stock_return    benchmark_return
    201301X     0.98    0.99
    201302X     1.03    1.01
    201303X     1.03    1
    201301Y     0.99    0.99
    201302Y     0.99    1.01
    201303Y     1.02    1

for every stock_return  benchmark_return I have to perform a operation such as stock_return(1)*stock_return(2)-benchmark_return(1)*benchmark_return(2)

i.e. 0.98*1.03- 0.99*1.01.

Kindly help me how do i do it using a do loop. I have to refer it to the every second observation using do loop

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to `LAG()` the values from the previous row.

Let's use a data step to create your data, but instead of mixing the month values with the stick id let's make them as two separate variables. Then we can use BY processing to tell when a new stock starts.

```
data have ;
  input month $6. stock_id $ stock_return benchmark_return ;
cards;
201301X 0.98 0.99
201302X 1.03 1.01
201303X 1.03 1
201301Y 0.99 0.99
201302Y 0.99 1.01
201303Y 1.02 1
;;;;
```

Now to create your new variable you just need use your formula, but you need to make sure not to do it for the first observation since the lagged values are for a different stock.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by stock_id month;
  new = lag(stock_return)*stock_return-lag(benchmark_return)*benchmark_return;
  if first.stock_id then new=.;
run;
```

Note that you do not want to put the `LAG()` function calls inside of a conditional.  The `LAG()` actually pulls the values from the previous executions of the function and not from the previous observations. So if skip executing it on every observation the value returned will not be the value from the previous observation.